# Is there a way to make grid lines on D3 barchart appear behind the bar? Using d3 + react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graph, bar-chart

I'm using d3 in a React project. Reading through SO posts, the main solution recommended is to make sure the grid lines are appended before the bar graph, as d3 doesn't have a z-index attr. I've done this, and it still isn't working – the grid lines are in front of the bars. Here's what it looks like: [image: bar chart with grid lines in front of bars]

Here's the code:

```
const BarChart = ({ data }) => {
  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) return;

    const numPlacement = n => {
      if (n > 100) return 2.4;
      if (n > 10) return 2.3;
      return 2.16;
    };

    let width = 800;
    let height = 500; 
    const svg = d3
      .select(svgRef.current)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("width", width);

    //scales
    let x = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(d => d.stage))
      .range([0, width]);

    let y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, Math.ceil(data[0].number / 10) * 10]) 
      .range([height, 0]);

    //axes
    let xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x);
    svg
      .select(".x-axis")
      .style("transform", `translateY(${height}px)`)
      .call(xAxisCall)
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("y", "20")
      .attr("font-size", "15");

    let yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y);
    svg.select(".y-axis").call(yAxisCall);

    //labels
    //x label bottom
    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "d3-label")
      .attr("y", height + 70)
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("font-size", "25px")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Stages");

    //top x label
    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "d3-label")
      .attr("y", -15)
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("font-size", "30px")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Job Hunt Progress");

    //y label
    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "d3-label")
      .attr("y", -60)
      .attr("x", -(height / 2))
      .attr("font-size", "25px")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .text("Number of Companies");

    //y lines
    const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft().scale(y);
    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      // .attr("id", "links")
      .call(
        makeYLines()
          .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
          .tickFormat("")
      );

    //bars
    svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)

      .join("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("transform", "scale(1, -1)")
      .attr("x", d => x(d.stage) + x.bandwidth() / 4)

      .attr("y", -height)
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() / 2)
      .transition()
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.number))
      .attr("fill", "#80cbc4 !important");

    svg
      .selectAll(".tooltip")
      .data(data)
      .join("text")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .text(v => (v.number > 0 ? v.number : null))
      .attr("fill", "#fff")
      .attr("x", v => x(v.stage) + x.bandwidth() / numPlacement(v.number))
      .attr("y", v => y(v.number) + (v.number > 4 ? 20 : 17))
      .transition()
      .attr("opacity", 1);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <HeaderContainer>
      <ChartArea>
        <SVG ref={svgRef}>
          <g className="x-axis" />
          <g className="y-axis" />
        </SVG>
      </ChartArea>
    </HeaderContainer>
  );
};
```

Sorry if I've included too much, I'm new to d3 and don't really know where the problem could be. If there's any other info that I should supply, please lmk. Hoping to solve this problem!

Comment: Can you post this code in some online editor. I am new to react but i can surely help on d3.js. I have done something similar in angular. if grid line is appended before bars it will come behind the bars

Comment: I think the problem is with React. I've appended the gridlines before the bars but it doesn't make a difference.